# How to handle IE specific browser confirm dialog using Watin Core?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, watin, browser-automation

I am using the below code for a basic search automation using Watin Core.

```
 IE ie = new IE();
 GoToNoWait("www.stackoverflow.com");
 ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("Test");
 ie.Button(Find.ByClass("btn js-search-submit")).Click();
```

But IE brings a pop up with the below message:

> When you send information to the Internet, it might be possible for
>   others to see that information. Do you want to continue?

Tried handling this using ConfirmDialogHandler but no luck. Any experts, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier for you to set this registry setting to 0 so no warning is shown. You will get other messages from IE but this one in particular won't be an issue:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3]"1601"=dword:00000000
```

(if you set it to 1 the message will be shown).